# Windows 8 desktop bounds change event

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8

I have a WinForms desktop application that needs to react to when the desktop bounds changes (or `WorkingArea`) due to an Metro App has been snapped to the left or right of the screen.

The `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` is not fired and cannot find a good alternative